# How to mock to execute oracle query to the in memory data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, moq

I am trying to write unit test to execute an oracle query to filter the in memory list of object.

How do i mock so that the filter condition will be applied to my in memory list of object rather than the actual database?

I could achieve this with the Entity Framework where I can mock the context and return in memory data but don't know how to achieve the same using `OracleCommand.ExecuteReader`.

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    var cmd = new OracleCommand
        {
            //TODO add Reg_Date in Where clause
            Connection = connection,
            CommandText =
                "SELECT mi.* from fromTable mi where 1=1 " 
                + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nuf) ? "" : " and mi.NUF != '"+ nuf +"'")
                + " and mi.Category<>'TES' and mi.Category<>'CVD'"
            CommandType = CommandType.Text
        };

    Debug.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);

    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: so when you execute the cmd what are you getting or not getting. also try constructing your query either calling a Stored Procedure but try not to use concatenated string to build the query.. you are setting yourself up for sql injection.

Comment: Sure. I will moving away from inline sql to stored procedure later. This does the querying on to the actual database. I want to query the in memory data and apply the filter so that i can unit test.

Comment: try returning the data as a DataTable and use the DataTables `Filer` function. so you can query off that ..there are plenty of working examples on how to do this as well on StackOverflow as well as the internet if you do a `Google Search on C# Stackoverflow DataTable.Filter` it will yield many results.

Comment: will it affect any performance? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: So far i know an in memory database will only be supported in EF Core. See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4293) discussion regarding EF Core and Oracle. Your best offer is to rewrite your code and use interfaces like IDbConnection. These interfaces can be mocked.

Answer (score 8):

Currently the method under test it too tightly coupled to implementation concerns to make it easily unit testable in isolation. Try abstracting those implementation concerns out so that they can be mocked easily for isolated tests.

```
public interface IDbConnectionFactory {
    IDbConnection CreateConnection();
}
```

The above connection factory abstraction can be used to access the other necessary `System.Data` abstractions of your Oracle data store.

```
public class MyDataAccessClass {
    private IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public MyDataAccessClass(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public object GetData(string nuf) {
        using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection()) {
            connection.Open();
            var query = "SELECT mi.* from fromTable mi where 1=1 " 
                        + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nuf) ? "" : " and mi.NUF != @nuf")
                        + " and mi.Category<>'TES' and mi.Category<>'CVD'"
            using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()){
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nuf)) {
                    var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
                    parameter.ParameterName = "@nuf";
                    parameter.Value = nuf;

                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(command.CommandText);

                var dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                //...other code removed for brevity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The production implementation of the factory will return an actual `OracleConnection`

```
public class OracleConnectionFactory: IDbConnectionFactory {
    public IDbConnection CreateConnection() {
        return new OracleConnection("connection string");
    }
}
```

which can be passed into the dependent class via dependency injection.

For testing you mock the interfaces using your mocking framework of choice or create your own fakes to inject and test your method.

```
[TestClass]
public class DataAccessLayerUnitTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFilter() {
        //Arrange
        var readerMock = new Mock<IDataReader>();

        var commandMock = new Mock<IDbCommand>();
        commandMock.Setup(m => m.ExecuteReader())
            .Returns(readerMock.Object)
            .Verifiable();

        var parameterMock = new Mock<IDbDataParameter>();            

        commandMock.Setup(m => m.CreateParameter())
            .Returns(parameterMock.Object);

        commandMock.Setup(m => m.Parameters.Add(It.IsAny<IDbDataParameter>()))
            .Verifiable();

        var connectionMock = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        connectionMock
            .Setup(m => m.CreateCommand())
            .Returns(commandMock.Object);

        var connectionFactoryMock = new Mock<IDbConnectionFactory>();
        connectionFactoryMock
            .Setup(m => m.CreateConnection())
            .Returns(connectionMock.Object);

        var sut = new MyDataAccessClass(connectionFactoryMock.Object);
        var input = "some value";

        //Act
        var data = sut.GetData(input);

        //Assert
        commandMock.Verify();
    }
}
```

Finally it is advisable that you use command parameters in the command text as constructing the query string manually with external values opens the code up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This sounds great, but if `CreateConnection()` has to return a mockable ÌDbConnection`(which is the whole point of the exercise), it can **not** return an **OracleConnection**. That kind of renders this whole idea unuable, which is a shame.

Comment: @oerkelens what are you referring to? `OracleConnection` is an implementation concern derived from `IDbConnection`. I think you are misunderstanding the concepts here. clarify where you have concerns.

Comment: I stared with defining DbConnection and IDbConnection, not realising they existed already and that OrackeConnection implements System.Data.DbConnection. Feeling stupid now... and happily moving on with your solution!

Comment: DbConnection is only useful as an abstraction over Oracle as long as you don't use any Oracle features or depend on any Oracle quirks. The moment you have to, say, use BindByName to avoid having to order your parameters, the abstraction gets thrown out the window.